# What is the question tag for "I used to swim in the Tilak tank"?

Tags: question-tags

What is the question tag that can be added to the following sentence?

> I used to swim in the Tilak tank.

This is question from an MCQ test whose options were

1. did I?
2. would I?

Comment: @Downvoter: What is wrong with the question? Please , suggest ?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but having additional information available only in a comment on an answer is very poor form.  If it's a multiple-choice question from a test, you should include the choices in your question and preferably specify where the question comes from.

Comment: The question as posted is incomplete. Please edit to provide context and show your efforts at research.

Comment: @MετάEd The question seems self-contained. Perhaps it *wasn't*.

Comment: @BhushanFirake Thank you for adding context; please also show your efforts at research. Doing your own research – and including the results of your efforts in the question – is a courtesy to the experts who will be trying to help you.

Comment: At a minimum, you should state what you think about each answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I used to swim in the Tilak tank, **didn't I?***

Comment: Actually, it's a multiple choice question and all options are a]did I? b]would I? Both of them are affirmative...can you explain , how you separate out did from "used to"? used to itself is an auxiliary verb...right?

Comment: _I used to swim in the Tilak tank, did I?_ is a possible English sentence. It might, for example, follow a comment by a parent reminiscing about what a child used to do. _Used to_ is a semi-modal verb.

Comment: @Bhushan Firake: I don't think there are *any* contexts where *"would I?"* could be a valid "question tag" for your example. The only difference between *"didn't I?"* and *"did I?"* is that the second is a (relatively unlikely) way of implying the speaker either disbelieves or is/would be surprised by an affirmative answer. Feasibly it might have been possible to say *"usen't I?"* a long time ago, but you certainly can't do that today.

Comment: @BhushanFirake Look [here](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/qu_tags.htm) for some rules for how to construct traditional question tags in English, including accounting for negatives and auxiliaries. Note that some speakers also use simpler tags like *“eh?”* or *“right?”*,  or even just *“ok?”* at the ends of their statements; *“you know?”* can be an all-purpose question tag in some speakers.

Comment: @tchrist:But all auxiliaries are not dealt there...

Comment: @BhushanFirake: You don't need to deal with every auxiliary verb to understand why _didn't I?_ is the appropriate question tag for the statement you have given. A few examples, if you observe carefully, will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Barrie England's answer. I am only going to explain why the correct question tag for the given statement is *didn't I?*

In the sentence "I used to swim in the Tilak tank", *used to* is not functioning as an auxiliary verb because *to* goes with the verb *swim* making it an *infinitive* leaving *used* as the only finite verb in the sentence. Hence there is a need for an auxiliary verb and *did* is required in this case since *used* is in the past tense.

And because the statement is affirmative, the question tag should be negative. That's how ***didn't I?*** becomes the correct question tag.

For more on question tags, please refer to the link provided by tchrist in the comments above. It's a good one.